# How to store redis hash in a datatable using c#

Tags: c#, redis

I am using redis for caching. I have stored the value in a redis hash. Now I have to store this redis hash in a datatable using c#. Let me know the best way for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can probably comment on the alternatives you have already thought about and maybe add one or two more to the set.

Comment: I have retrieved the all the values from hash and it is now in a var variable named a(say for eg).My code is as below: var allHash = db.SetMembers("VALUE:ID");

            //get key and values
            // var getall = db.HashGetAll("user:" + txtid.Text);

            for (int i = 0; i < allHash.Length; i++)
            {
                a = db.HashValues("VALUE:" + allHash[i]);
         
          
            }.Now I need to bind the values at a to a gridview using c#.How can I do this.Is there any way out

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = null;
foreach (HashEntry entry in db.HashGetAll("user:1"))
{                           
    dt.Columns.Add(entry.Name);
    dr[entry.Name] = entry.Value;
}
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```